# How to create routes in react-router-dom? I got an error component is not define

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

```
import Home from './components/Home';
import { Routes, Route, Router} from "react-router-dom";
import Products from './components/Products';
```

```
<Router>
 <Routes>

 <Route exact path="/"  element={component={Home}} />
<Route exact path="/products"  element={component={Products}} />


 </Routes>
 </Router>
```

I try every method but unable to resolve the issue. Kindly help me with this error.

Comment: You've some typos in your route declarations. `element={component={Home}}` should just be `element={<Home />}`. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or caused by typo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with the element={component={Home}}. Assuming that you are using latest react-router-dom. The syntax is element={}. Your code should look like this:

```html
import Home from './components/Home';
import { Routes, Route, Router} from "react-router-dom";
import Products from './components/Products';
<Router>
 <Routes>

 <Route exact path="/"  element={<Home/>} />
<Route exact path="/products"  element={<Products/>} />


 </Routes>
 </Router>
```

And if you are latest react-router-dom then you do not need to wrap everything inside  components. You can remove it.